Error in DockerFiles in AzureDevOps environment
When performing the buils of a Net project. 7, in the DockerFile file I get an error in the following section:
RUN dotnet build "./Inventario/./Inventario.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app


Error: error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method
suitable for an entry point [/src/Inventario/Inventario.csproj]

Code DockerFile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./Inventario.csproj", "Inventario/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Inventario/./Inventario.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "./Inventario/./Inventario.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Inventario.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false 

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Inventario.dll"]

What could be wrong with the DockerFile?
Thank you in advance, best regards
What could be wrong with the DockerFile?
Code YML:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Docker Build
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |          
      find . -name "Dockerfile"            
      docker build -t service:$(tag) .
      docker save service:$(tag) -o service_$(tag).tar


Hi there, If building the docker file locally, will the issue be reproduced? It would be helpful to isolate the issue to be called by the docker file or environment. Thx.

No, it works locally without any problems.

Can you please share your pipeline YAML definition to help understand the workflow? Please don't include any sensitive information like password token cert etc in the post, as the information is visible to public. Thanks.

added in the main question. Thank you

Hi Alberto, I could see your script was building the Dockerfile, which generated container to build your dotnet project. But from the error message, it seemed your project lacked required method. Have you tried to run docker build to build image with the same docker file locally? If possible, may I know what your dotnet program of this project looks like and if it contains the Main method?

Hi @AlbertoPuigdomenech, Have you got a chance to check the answer by Kevin below? Can you please confirm if the project profiles were copied to the correct path in your dockerfile when building your docker image? You mentioned building the docker file locally works without any problems. Did you build the same dockerfile locally? Thx for taking time to share the update.

Hi @AlbertoPuigdomenech, Can you please let us know the status of the issue and does the answer by Kevin below works to resolve it?

The project is in NET7, there is no MAIN procedure. That's the problem I'm facing.

If your .Net7 project lacked the MAIN procedure, the project files to build the docker image should also lack the MAIN procedure, right? But why building your dockerfile works locally even there was no MAIN procedure during image building?


Error: error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/Inventario/Inventario.csproj]

I can reproduce the same issue when using the similar dockerfile.

The cause of the issue is that you are copying the .csproj file to the Inventario/(COPY ["./Inventario.csproj", "Inventario/"]), but all other project files are copied to the root folder(COPY . .).
In this case, the dotnet build command not able to find the Program.cs to find the main method.
To solve this issue, you need to copy the .csproj file and other project files to the same folder(root folder or Inventario/ folder).
For example:  you can copy all files to Inventario/ folder
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./Inventario.csproj", "Inventario/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Inventario/./Inventario.csproj"
COPY . Inventario/
RUN dotnet build "./Inventario/./Inventario.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Inventario.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false 

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Inventario.dll"]

